# linker error: what could be going on?

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, linker

I know not many people have telepathic powers here, but I will try to give as much info as I can so someone can help me debug what I think is a linker error in some program I'm trying to compile.

So, the program is `cilkprof` (see [here](https://secure-software.intel.com/en-us/system/files/article/182363/cilkutil-linux-2516-v12.tgz), warning: tgz file). Within it is a `Makefile` for which I only changed the var `CXX = icpc` to `CXX = g++`. All else is equal.

```
/usr/bin/ld: ../../3rdparty/pintool/intel64/lib/libpin.a(util_host_ia32e.os): 
relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `DoXsave' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [linux64/cilkprof.so] Error 1
```

I know I should be understanding that `libpin.a` should be recompiled with `-fPIC`, but the pin version I have is already compiled. Any idea what I may be doing wrong? Please ask if something is not clear. Thanks.

Comment: are you trying to build a shared library ?

Comment: @mux: yes, it's a .so library

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the Makefile is trying to build a shared library and link it to a static non-PIC library, which is AFAIK, something you can't do. So if you can not recompile the libray with `-fPIC` then the only solution I see is to modify the Makefile and build a static library instead.